# Optimizing C code with lots of dereferences

Tags: c, optimization

Linux `perf` and GPerfTools `pprof` give me a lot of stalled frontend and backend cycles at this piece of code:

```
for(j = oL; j < oR; j++) {
   T[j].v = (T[j].x / div)*K+T[j].y /div;
   T[j].x = T[j].x % div;
   T[j].y = T[j].y % div;        
   counterK[T[j].k]++;
  }
```

gives me:

```
 9.973.660.617 stalled-cycles-frontend   #   42,16% frontend cycles idle   
 4.874.722.502 stalled-cycles-backend    #   20,60% backend  cycles idle
```

I understand that stalled cycles mean that the instruction pipeline cannot really advance, waiting for (maybe) some data from memory. I can see that there are a lot of dereferencing poniters to struct members in that piece of code, and that may be a problem, but I'm afraid I lack sufficient knowledge to see any optimization there. Could anyone help?

Comment: I don't think it's the structs causing issues.  I'm pretty sure it's using `T[j]` all over the place.  If you used a `struct *temp = &T[j]` and used `temp->` instead, you'll probably see better results.

Comment: More likely it's the inability to reorder loads and stores (or cache values in a register) since .x and .y are being both modified and consumed as inputs to expressions, and it's not clear whether `counterK` may alias `T`, plus the fact that division and modulo are rather expensive operations (~20 cycles). And of course, there's formally creation of a lot of temps, so the types in that struct had better be PODs or you be copying them many times.

Comment: may be somme very small stuff : use ++var; instead of var++; pre-incrementation is faster cause it doesn't create a temporary variable, and I agree with Mr. Llama. If the variable "div" is a power of two you can also do a great one. Unfortunatly, divisons are slow.

Comment: @Damon: Thanks. I agree with the L&S. If by POD you mean plain old data, then yes, they are `int`s. But I never heard anyone talking about POD outside of OO, and this is pure C :)

Comment: @Damon, this is C, so your comment about POD doesn't apply. Also, `counterK` is of some integer base type and `T` of some `struct` type. Since they have different type, C will never assume that they alias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dereferencing `struct` pointers by itself should not be a problem on modern architectures. They can do relative addressing and cope quite well with such accesses. Also aliasing as mentioned in one comment shouldn't be a problem. `*T` and `*counterK` have different types, so C will never suppose that they alias.

Often, for such loops as you are showing us the processor/memory bandwidth is the bottelneck and not the speed of the processor. So may be, you are just at the limit that your memory can serve.

You are accessing `T` sequentially, this is already the best you can do for it. The only optimization possible for `T` would be that you have a lot of fields in it that are not used by the loop that you are showing us. Then you might be wasting processor / memory bandwidth. Then compacting things in an array that has just the information that is needed might help.

For `counterK` things are more complicated, because the information that you give use has no hint about the access pattern or the size of the array. If `counterK` is large (much larger than your L1 cache) and your access is very irregular, the stalls could come from here.

Comment: I tried the dereferencing, and it now went down half a sec, lowering the frontend by 1% (from 42% to 41%), and the backend considerably by 3% (from 20% to 17%)... but these are micro optimizations at this point...